# Whats the difference between these two buttons? Android programming

Tags: android, eclipse

Ok ive just started programming some android in Eclipse, and im a little dumbfounded about this. Here are two ways that the button programming has been written in this book, they both work fine, except the first one seems simpler and shorter. Which is better and why?

```
View newButton = findViewById(R.id.main_new_button);
newButton.setOnClickListener(this);


Button newButton= (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.main_new_button);
newButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

The two forms are equivalent. In both cases `findViewById` returns a `View` object, the only difference is that in the second version an explicit cast is made to `Button`, a subclass of `View`.

As you can see in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html), `View` is the superclass of `TextView`, and `TextView` is the superclass of `Button`.

Which one is better? it depends. If you need to use functionality specific to a `Button`, then the second way is preferred. On the other hand, if a `View` object suffices, then use the first way.

Answer (score 1):

I like your way of thinking.In android every widget is view.I will tell you in step--

## 1)

First important thing is Every Button is View but not necessarily Every View should button

```
  View newButton = findViewById(R.id.main_new_button);
  newButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

you are using it that does not mean that newButton is always a Button.We can stroe any View reference (for ex. LinearLayout, ImageButton etc) to newButton

But In second case

```
Button newButton= (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.main_new_button);
newButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

newButton is definitely should be Button if R.id.main_new_button is button ID in XML

## 2)-

> As i said we know every Button is View but we do not know which View is button.That's it ask you to cast findViewByid.And your first case discourage as every view has its own method that can not be used if we generalize this view.So we have to use specifically Button.

Hope you got it

Comment: Did it help you to solve your issue? then consider question to accept answer

Answer (score 0):

A Button is a widget which extends a TextView. A TextView extends a View. If you go for the Button class, you will be exposed to more specific member functions rather than the aforementioned super classes. As far as what those specific methods are... you would have to go into the android.widget.Button class to explore that =). Upon doing this, all I see are three constructors (for explicitly declaring the button) -- all other member functions are identical.

```
 public Button(android.content.Context context);
 public Button(android.content.Context context, android.util.AttributeSet attrs);
 public Button(android.content.Context context, android.util.AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle);
```

But if you don't want to confuse yourself down the line when you come back to this code after 3 months, or the other developers working along side with you, the second method is the proper method to use:

```
Button newButton= (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.main_new_button);
newButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button, you need the latter formation. The formmer formation is ok but it's not the perfect method.Because the view's usage is not only for button.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, you have cast the result to the correct type. This allows you to access `Button`-specific methods. The first one returns just a `View` object although it is a `Button`. So you will not have access to `Button`-specific functionality.

Comment: I just noticed that `Button` does not define any public methods of its own. My point still holds though, because `Button` extends from `TextView`, which has a lot more functionality that just `View`.

Answer (score 0):

The button which is built by View is a view, not a button widget.If you create a button from a View Class,you could not call the functions of Button Class. View Class and Button Class both have the "setOnClickListener" function,but that function of View Class is not the same as it from Button.